# Chromium Content Shell for Android not showing video

Tags: chromium

I've built latest (36.0.1985.131) chromium Content Shell for Android.
target Android version is 4.3.

I've installed and able to see html5 pages on it. But when trying to play video(youtube or resident mp4), I can here only the audio, black screen on page. On pressing back a glimpse of currently plying video in background is seen.

Steps to reproduce:
1.Open Content Shell on Android
2.Go to www.youtube.com and click whatever video
3.Video plays but nothing displayed on page (only audio heard)

I guess video decoding is happening but some how not able to update/delegate the same information to page.

The command line flags used to run content shell is :
--enable-top-controls-position-calculation --top-controls-height=87.0 --top-controls-show-threshold=0.27 --top-controls-hide-threshold=0.17 --enable-high-end-ui-undo --enable-begin-frame-scheduling --enable-threaded-compositing --enable-fixed-position-compositing --enable-accelerated-overflow-scroll --enable-begin-frame-scheduling --enable-gesture-tap-highlight --enable-pinch --enable-overlay-fullscreen-video --enable-overlay-scrollbar --enable-overscroll-notifications --in-process-gpu --disable-gpu-shader-disk-cache --enable-viewport --enable-viewport-meta --main-frame-resizes-are-orientation-changes --disable-composited-antialiasing --ui-prioritize-in-gpu-process --enable-delegated-renderer --profiler-timing=0 --prerender=enabled --prerender-from-omnibox=enabled --flag-switches-begin --flag-switches-end --disable-gpu-watchdog --supports-dual-gpus=false --gpu-driver-bug-workarounds=1,7,8,42,44 --disable-webrtc-hw-encoding --gpu-vendor-id=0x0000 --gpu-device-id=0x0000 --gpu-driver-vendor --gpu-driver-version=0 --enable-instant-extended-api

Any help, suggestion, idea to crack this will be appreciated.

Thanks
Dip